# a:visited not working in edge chromium, is there a workaround?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I'm having trouble getting my visited hyperlinks to show as visited in Edge Chromium. I've been reading through the forums and understand that due to security concerns the functionality has been limited. Does anyone here know of a work around?

Update: I've added the code for the hyperlink, it looks like my issue may be caused by the use of "javascript:void" which does not set the link to visited. I'll need to figure out a way to avoid the use of it here.

```
<style>
a:link { color: green }
a:visited { color: pink }
a:hover { color: red }
a:active { color: orange }
</style>


<a title='<%=alttext%>''alt='<%=alttext%>' href="javascript:void(window.open('oneJob.asp?key=<%=jnum%>','_onejob'));">
<%=partorppid%>
</a>
```

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#privacy_restrictions), styling of `color` should be possible without problem. It seems to work fine for me in Edge.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i must have something overriding it. It's a bit baffling as the hover and link colors work fine. But the visited doesn't show at all when I inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the order of your pseudo-class. Please try the following order:

```
<style>
a:link { color: green }
a:visited { color: pink }
a:hover { color: red }
a:active { color: orange }
</style>
```

It is also mentioned in the MDN [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#try_it):

> Styles defined by the :visited pseudo-class will be overridden by any subsequent link-related pseudo-class (:link, :hover, or :active) that has at least equal specificity. To style links appropriately, put the :visited rule after the :link rule but before the :hover and :active rules, as defined by the LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is a bit hacky, but it is working in all browsers at the moment. I removed the javascript void and added an onclick event to open the window.
I added in href="#" but that resulted in all the links on the page showing as visited after a single click. Leaving in the path after the href="# solved that.

```
<a title='<%=alttext%>''alt='<%=alttext%>' onClick="window.open('oneJob.asp?key=<%=jnum%>','_onejob')" href="#('oneJob.asp?key=<%=jnum%>','_onejob');">
```